# Android Studio: How to add new Components to Palette?

Tags: android-studio

How do I add new components (like SpinEdits etc.) and categories to my palette? Other sites points to the SDK Manager, but I installed all the SDK Tools and it did not work. I could not find any other option there for adding new components.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Because of the vast amount of information on the internet and Stack Overflow, it often takes just a simple search or two to find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them as dependencies to your project structure.
Go to File -> Project Structure.

However, you should first consider what feature you want to add. You can add any feature by typing the artifact it belongs to. Of course, you can find its artifact in its documentation page. For example, if you are trying to add CardView,
then you should go to this page:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView

and you should find its artifact as: 
com.android.support  cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1